# How to know the number of disk I/O in Sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I am using sqlite in my program and want to tune some parameters to improve performance, so I want to know how to get the number of disk I/O when executing queries in sqlite. Anybody can help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling [`sqlite3_db_status()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/db_status.html) with [`SQLITE_DBSTATUS_CACHE_MISS`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_dbstatus_options.html#sqlitedbstatuscachemiss):

> This parameter returns the number of pager cache misses that have occurred.